# Modelling a graph with classes 'edge' and 'node'

Tags: c++, oop, graph

I have to model an unweighted graph in C++ and do BFS and DFS. But, I have to create two separate classes: `node` and `edge` which would contain the two extremities of type `node`. I do not understand how would I be able to do any search in the graph using the `edge` class. If it were me, I would only create the `node` class and have the neighbours of node X in a list/array inside the class. Is there something I am missing? How could I take advantege of the class `edge`? Is there any way to do the searches without using an adjacency matrix or list? Thank you!

Comment: If the graph is weighted, where do you think the edge weight should be stored without an `edge` class?

Comment: @Lingxi it is not a weighted graph.

Comment: @rptoma The graph *you* are working with *today* is not weighed. Should it be a factor in designing a general-purpose graph data structure?

Comment: You can construct an adjacency matrix or list from an edge list for graph search purpose.

Comment: @n.m. Yes. I am new to OOP and have to model the graph as described earlier in order to understand better how OOP works.

Comment: @Lingxi Yes, I thought about it, but I was told that I am not allowed to do it... I even mentioned at the end of the post.

Comment: You said you "have to" create two separate classes. Is this a school assignment?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it is. I am not trying to get my homework done, I am trying to understand how things work... I have searched all over the internet for an answer.

Comment: BTW OOP has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I don't understand what question you still have. Is it why you personally need a class for graph edges for your current project? Or is it why having such a class is a good idea in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use adjacency lists. But they will contain not references to other nodes, but rather references to edge instances, which in turn contain both endpoints as node references, as you mention. Of course, that seems kind of redundant because if you have, say `source` and `target` nodes in each edge and then you access some edge of a given node using something like `node.edges[i].source`, then you instantly know that this `source` is the `node` itself, otherwise this edge wouldn't even be in this node's adjacency list. But `source` may still be useful if you pass a reference to edge alone somewhere, where you don't have the source node at hand.

That aside, for the simplest graph this kind of approach seems like an overkill, because edges only store source and destination edges, the former being mostly redundant. But you may need to extend your edge class later with something like weights, labels, auxiliary data like residual flow or something like that. So having such class is a nice idea after all.

Moreover, some algorithms work directly on edges. For example, you may need to search for an edge satisfying some criterion. Having a separate class gives you freedom to create lists of edges without ad-hoc approaches like `pair<Node, Node>` or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I am encountering a problem, though. The edge class won't be able to see the node class and vice versa. I saw that this can be solved with forward declaration and pointers like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964482/how-to-create-two-classes-in-c-which-use-each-other-as-data),  but I don't completely understand. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @rptoma, this is a completely different question. I suggest you study the subject first, then ask a new question if something is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the constant of space complexity in storing the edges.
When you store the edges in adjacency matrix/list, you have to store both (node1, node2) and (node2, node1) for each edge.
You double the space, although the big-O complexity stays the same.
However, there're times when such space constant has to be considered.

You can take advantage of the class edge when you would like to save as much space as possible, and you would like to prioritize space over time.

Linear search on all the edge instances is a way.
Linear search is slow but you prioritize space over time.
Maybe parallel search when you have a distributed system is another way, but you have to verify.

Your homework question may have an artificial constraint of the design of the edge class. Artificial constraint idea comes from https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions