# How to create two classes including each other with inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have just seen similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964482/how-to-create-two-classes-in-c-which-use-each-other-as-data/4964508) but that doesn't solve my problem, because I'm struggling with inheritance. That's how my simplified code looks:

Game.h

```
#include "Ghost.h"

class Game
{
   Ghost * myGhost;
};
```

Ghost.h

```
#include "MovableItem.h"

class Ghost : public MovableItem
{
   Ghost(Game * parentGame) : MovableItem(parentGame)
   {
   }
};
```

MovableItem.h

```
class MovableItem
{
   MovableItem(Game * parentGame);
};
```

When I'm trying to use forward declaration of class Game, I get 'invalid use of incomplete type class Game' compilation error and without that declaration I get 'Game does not name a type'. How can I solve that problem? Thanks for advance.

Comment: You likely forgot to include the header containing the forward declared type in your implementation files.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, I was making forward declaration in header file and then I should include in cpp header to class that I want to refer. Problem solved. Thanks.