# C++: How to create 2 classes which use each other

Tags: c++, c++14

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964482/how-to-create-two-classes-in-c-which-use-each-other-as-data) gives answer only when the classes use each other as the *member types*, but not when they use the *functions* of each other. How to do it in the following example? `Bar` is a singleton container which handles the operations done on all `Bar`s.

```cpp
// Foo.h

#include "Bar.h"

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { Bar::get_instance()->push_back(this); }

    void do_something() {}
};
```

```cpp
// Bar.h

#include "Foo.h"
#include <vector>

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(const Bar &other) = delete;

    void operator=(const Bar &) = delete;

    static Bar *get_instance()
    {
        static Bar bar;
        return &bar;
    }

    void push_back(Foo *foo) { foos_.push_back(foo); }

    void do_something_all() { for (Foo *f : foos_) f->do_something(); }

private:
    Bar() = default;

    std::vector<Foo *> foos_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forward declaration** will do the trick, forward decalre in .h and include the header in cpp.

```
// Bar.h

//#include "Foo.h"
#include <vector>

class Foo; // <---- this one

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(const Bar &other) = delete;

    void operator=(const Bar &) = delete;

    static Bar *get_instance();

    // move definition in cpp
    void push_back(Foo *foo);

    // move definition in cpp
    void do_something_all();

private:
    Bar() = default;

    std::vector<Foo *> foos_;
};
```

// Bar.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

Bar* Bar::get_instance()
{
    static Bar bar;
    return &bar;
}

void Bar::push_back(Foo *foo) 
{ 
   foos_.push_back(foo); 
}
    
void Bar::do_something_all() 
{ 
   for (Foo *f : foos_) f->do_something();
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do this, this is exactly what's suggested in the answer I was referring to. But the compiler (or at least IDE) doesn't see the ```Foo```'s ```do_something()``` function.

Comment: @kenticent move definition in .cpp. you can freely include bar.h there.

Answer (score 3):

You split it up. Define the classes but put the implementation part after the class definition.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(); // declare but do not implement

    // this can be implemented here since it doesn't need Bar:
    void do_something() { std::cout << "Foo::do_something()\n"; }
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(const Bar&) = delete;
    void operator=(const Bar&) = delete;

    static Bar& get_instance() { // return a reference instead
        static Bar bar;
        return bar;
    }

    // you can store a pointer - but require a reference:
    void push_back(Foo& foo) { foos_.push_back(&foo); }

    // or else you need to check for nullptr in here:
    void do_something_all() { for(Foo* f : foos_) f->do_something(); }

private:
    Bar() = default;

    std::vector<Foo*> foos_;
};

// Implementation part:
// Here Foo can use Bar

Foo::Foo() {
    Bar::get_instance().push_back(*this);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vnK83T)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted as this is also the answer to my question.